# CocoaPods not importing SDK frameworks properly

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, dropbox-api, cocoapods

I have been trying to import the `Dropbox-iOS-SDK` into my project through `CocoaPods`, but the framework file doesn't seem to be imported properly. My `Podfile` looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
pod 'Reachability'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.9'
pod "Dropbox-iOS-SDK"
```

I am new to `CocoaPods` and I'm not sure where I am going wrong. I tried cleaning the project and restarting `Xcode`. But the Pods Frameworks file still looks like this:

[image]

As a result of this I am getting the following errors during build:

[image]

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: The pods go into Pods -> Pods -> PodName (Dropbox-iOS-SDK). The "Frameworks" folder is just for Cocoa Frameworks.

Comment: Ok so then I have to manually drag and drop these framework files into my project?

Comment: You shouldn't need to no. Perhaps something is bugged up with the DropBox Cocoapod.

Comment: Hmm. Well, in fact this is happening to other API's I'm trying to add - Pinterest, Flurry and google-plus-ios-sdk. I'm inclined to think I went wrong in the cocoa pods installation somewhere. But then, AFNetworking, SDWebImage, Facebook and Reachability worked like a charm. :/

Comment: What version of CocoaPods are you using? Always make sure your installation is up to date.

Comment: I was adding cocoa pods to an existing project and so I had to remove references to all paths to previously imported frameworks and headers. Once I removed these, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was adding cocoa pods to an existing project and so I had to remove references to all paths to previously imported frameworks and headers. Once I removed these, everything worked fine.

This is in case someone runs into the same problem.

Comment: Thank you! I renamed a project and I was having a heck of a time getting a new cocoapod installed. I didn't see the old files referenced anywhere in the code, yet I was getting a linker error. Upon stumbling into this post, I looked at the files and found a remnant of the prior project, deleted it and I'm good to go. (Anyone reading this, don't do what I did unless you've got a backup file or a you're using `git` in case you delete something you're not supposed to.

Answer (score 5):

Same response as Rameez with more precision :
As I had previously added libraries without Cocoapod, my project settings were not clean. When running pod install, the "Framework search path" and "header search path" were not set correctly.

To get the correct value for those two search path :

1. create an empty project
2. add the previous podfile in the new project (just change the target name)
3. run pod install
4. Look at the Framework and header search path values in the new project
5. Copy-paste those values into your previous project settings

Comment: I just tried this, and the Frameworks still aren't connecting: http://d.pr/i/AvuP ... what do your framework search paths look like?

Comment: My framework search path is : "$(PODS_ROOT)/Parse"
Header path is : "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Parse" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Reachability"

You need the header path line for each of your pods and the framework search path for some of them only

Comment: This solved my issue. I also added linker flags from the new project. The Framework search paths were missing, but the header search paths were correct. Not sure why this happens though...

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was with `Other Linker Flags` and `Runpath Search Paths`, which weren't inheriting the settings defined on `xcconfig`. The following adjustments solved my problem:

**Other Linker Flags**:

```
$(inherited)
```

**Runpath Search Paths**:

```
$(inherited)
@executable_path/Frameworks
```

Answer (score -1):

After pod setup successfully-
Take This steps-

1] touch podfile

2] open -e podfile

You will then get a text editor file. Now add your files properly.
Now Save that and close that window and your Project window also.
Go to Finder and you will get an proj.workspace file.
Open That one.

Now..........
now under xcode.proj you will find an proj.test. Go there and change deployment Target with your project name.